# Do I need to import Pinia store props multiple times in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am working on my first Vue project. I'm used to React and vanilla js, but just getting my head around a few concepts in Vue here.

In particular, importing state and action props from a Pinia store, and seemingly having to import those multiple times in a single Vue component (something I don't need to do in React).

In this example, I am importing a simple count value, and an increment function, and trying to use these in a few different places:

```
<script setup>
// I import everything initially in setup, which works fine,
// and these props (currentCount and incrementCount)
// can be used in my template:
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useStore } from '@/stores/store';
const { currentCount } = storeToRefs(useStore());
const { incrementCount } = useStore();
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    Current count: {{ currentCount }}
    <button @click="incrementCount">Increment</button>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
// I can't use store values from setup here.
// This doesn't work:
// console.log(currentCount);

// I also can't import store values here.
// I get the following error:
// "getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia"
// const { currentCount } = storeToRefs(useStore());

export default {
  mounted() {
    // I have to import store values here for them to work:
    const { currentCount } = storeToRefs(useStore());
    console.log(currentCount);
  },
  watch: {
    // weirdly, this reference to watching "currentCount" works:
    currentCount() {
      // I also have to import store values here for them to work:
      const { currentCount } = storeToRefs(useStore());
      console.log(currentCount);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, if I want to use store values in my template, on mount, and in a watcher (whereby I'd use React's useEffect hook) I am having to import the store props 3 times in total.

Is this correct / normal? Is there a simpler way to achieve what I'm doing, where I only import props once? I want to be sure I haven't missed something and am not doing something in an unusual way.

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: Where are you defining `currentBrightness`?

Comment: @a.h.g. copy and paste error, updated now - should have been currentCount as sued elsewhere

Comment: `useStore()` should be used only inside the `setup()`. If you are not using Composition API, you should read [Usage without setup()](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html)

Comment: I hope I've answered your question. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pinia was designed with Composition API in mind.
So its intended usage is inside `setup()` function, where you'd only import it once.

To use it outside of a `setup()` function, you have two main routes:

- inside components, you can just return it from `setup()` and it becomes available in any hook/method/getter. Either as `this.store` or spread:

```
import { useStore } from '@/store'
import { toRefs } from 'vue'
            // or from '@vue/composition-api' in Vue2

export default {
  setup: () => ({ ...toRefs(useStore()) })
}
/* this makes every state prop, getter or action directly available 
   on current component instance. In your case, `this.currentCount`.
   Obviously, you can also make the entire store available as `this.someStore`:

  setup: () => ({ someStore: useSomeStore() })
  // now you can use `this.someStore` anywhere 
 */
```

- a more general approach is to export the `pinia` instance (returned by `createPinia()`), from `main.(js|ts)`, import it where you need the store and then call `useStore()` passing the pinia instance as an argument.
  This can be done anywhere, even outside of components.
  Generic example:

```
import { pinia } from 'main.js'
import { useSomeStore } from '@/store'

const someStore = useSomeStore(pinia);
```

---

I should probably also mention the `mapState` helper provided by `pinia`. It allows you to select only a few of the keys exposed to current instance. Example:

```
import { mapState } from 'pinia'
// ...
   computed: {
    ...mapState(useSomeStore, [ 'currentCount'])
  }
// Now `this.currentCount` is available
```

Note: `mapState` is weirdly named, as it allows you to access more than just `state` props (also `getters` and `actions`). It was named `mapState` to match the similar helper from `vuex`.

---

An even more general approach is to add your store as global, using the plugin registration API in Vue2:

```
import { useSomeStore } from '@/store';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

const pinia = createPinia();

const someStorePlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.someStore = useSomeStore(options.pinia)
  }
};

Vue.use(someStorePlugin, { pinia });

new Vue({ pinia });
```

After this, every single component of your Vue instance will have `this.someStore` available on it, without you needing to import it.

Note: I haven't tested adding a store in globals (and I definitely advise against it - you should avoid globals), but i expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you, this has been helpful in understanding the different APIs! I think I came across a variety of different ways of working and wasn't sure what to use when, but this clears things up. I am now using the Composition API to achieve what I need. Looks like you edited your answer a lot since I first checked it out, but both were helpful.

Comment: It's more or less the same info, just better structured, methinks. You're quite welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear explanation man. This should be put in as clear terms in the documentation.

Comment: Store as globals working only i vue2? Does ti work in vue3?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine `pinia` stores with the options API, one way to do it is to use the `setup()` function inside the options to call `useStore`:

```js
<script>
import { useStore } from '@/stores/store';

export default {
  setup() { 
    const store = useStore();
    return {store}
  },
  watch: {
    store.currentBrightness(newVal, oldVal){
      // your code
    }
  },
  methods: {
   // inside methods use this.store
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.store.currentCount);
  }
}
</script>
```

Some might consider this as a unwanted mix of composition and options API, but in my view it is a quite good solution for pinia stores.

Answer (score 1):

Nechoj, has the most straightforward answer. Also if you have multiple stores you can always import the stores as necessary into a parent component then use inject just add some parts. For example I have a route data that is called via an api, I don't need it everywhere all the time so i call it in a parent then use inject to use those routes in a drop down that might be a great grandchild component. I don't need that whole utils store just the routes.
index page:

```
import { useUtilsStore } from "src/stores/utilsStore";
const passengerRoutes = computed(() => utilsStore.getPassengerRoutes);
provide("passengerRoutes", passengerRoutes);
```

grandchild component:

```
const compRoutes = inject("passengerRoutes");
```